# SQL - Aggregating Data

Tags: sql, select, aggregate, distinct

I've got a sql query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     cast (a.event_timestamp  as date) as DATE
    ,a.label 
    ,COUNT (a.event_row_id) as VISITS
    ,COUNT (DISTINCT a.event_row_id) as UNIQUE_VISITORS
FROM all_page_visits_alias_vw a
WHERE CAST (event_timestamp as date) >= '2018-01-01'
GROUP by a.label, a.event_timestamp
```

This resulted in the following table where a date appears multiple times. Ex:

```
DATE|LABEL|VISITS|UNIQUE_VISITORS
18-12-2019| A | 1 | 1
18-12-2019| A | 3 | 1
18-12-2019| A | 4 | 1
```

It should have been:

```
DATE|LABEL|VISITS|UNIQUE_VISITORS
18-12-2019| A | 8 | 3
```

What did do wrong? How come there is no aggregation on label and date level?

With kind regards,

LaZZaNoVa

I've tried writing the code above, but the results were different than expected.

Comment: `.. group by a.label, cast (a.event_timestamp  as date)`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` when `GROUP BY` raises many eye-brows.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by the timestamp to date as well.  when you group by the timestamp you're getting the time component grouped.  It's just not being displayed because of your select.

```
SELECT 
     cast (a.event_timestamp  as date) as DATE
    ,a.label 
    ,COUNT (a.event_row_id) as VISITS
    ,COUNT ( DISTINCT a.event_row_id) as UNIQUE_VISITORS
FROM all_page_visits_alias_vw a
WHERE CAST (event_timestamp as date) >= '2018-01-01'
GROUP by a.label, cast (a.event_timestamp  as date)
```

Comment: This did the trick... Thanks xQbert!